# Sha512 wont work... please help CODEIGNITER

Tags: codeigniter, sha512

so i have this function **login** containing an array that gets the value of **email** and **password**, i encrypted the password with sha512 in another function but it seems that it has a problem, when i tired looging in password wont work., i tired revising my code though it doesn't display an error.  i think the problem is in the database. i'm using xampp 1.8.3 with database server of 5.6.16.. i'm newbie in codeigniter so please rescue me..Thank you in advance.....

```
 public function login(){
       $user = $this->get_by(array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password')),
       ), TRUE);
}

public function hash($string){
      return hash('sha512', $string . config_item('encryption_key'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What database field are you using to hold the data? Sha512 returns a rather large character count, you will need at least 255 chars for your password field?